# Forecasting/prediction using ARIMA in python - how does it work?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, arima, pmdarima

I am very confused about how to predict/forecast using ARIMA.

Lets assume we have a series called `y_orig` that we split into `y_train` and `y_test`. Assuming that `y_orig` is not stationary, we could fit ARIMA using the code below

```
# fit ARIMA model
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(y_train, order=(2,1,2))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
```

After fitting the model, we can predict using the code below

```
n_periods = len(`y_test`)

fc, -, - = model_fit.forecast(n_periods, alpha=0.05)  # 95% conf
```

The value `fc` should give a forecast which i then compare to `y_test`. Please note that as expected, `y_test` is not used in the training phase. Also note that i am not looking for a rolling forecast but for a long term forecast where the parameters (once trained) are fixed.

I am very confused because `y_test` is not used at all in the forecasting phase.
For instance, if we were to use other prediction models (like in Keras or tensorflow). we would be coding it that way.

First, we fit the model in the training phase which i dont show- it does not matter for my question. Then we predict and see how good our fit is `in sample` using the code below.

```
y_pred_train=model.predict(y_train)
```

then we test the model `out of sample` as below:

```
y_pred_test=model.predict(y_test)
```

In this situation, the parameters are not re-estimated and `y_test` is used in the testing phase to forecast the next value (with fixed parameters).

Hence my confusion with ARIMA.  Why do we not do the same with ARIMA model?

Please help me understand as i am very confused.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused by the `.fit` and the `y_train` in the `ARIMA` code block. `y_train` is just a poorly named variable here, it should just be `y`, the data I want to forecast. The `ARIMA` model has no training/test phase, it's not self-learning. It does a statistical analysis of the input data, and does a forecast. If you want to do another forecast (on `y_test`), you need to do another statistical analysis (using `model.fit`) and do another forecast (using `model.forecast`). The `ARIMA` model does not have any `weights` it trains in a training phase, nothing related to any previous data 'fitted' on is saved in the model. You can't use a "fitted" `ARIMA` model to forecast other data samples.

Comment: Frederik thanks very much!!. But 'how can I test the validity of the forecast if i dont compare it to a test data?'   'Are you suggesting that doing a rolling forecast is more appropriate?' and 'that i can only forecast one step at a time?'...If so, then ARIMA model wont be comparable with a model where parameters are fixed..... finally, in case of ARIMA,  'is it not possible to do multiple step ahead forecast without re-estimating the parameters?'   sorry i am a bit confused

Comment: To get an accuracy (=test the validity of the forecast) for `ARIMA`, take N sequences of time series data, chop of the last `M` values of each sequence , fit  a new `ARIMA` model on each of the first `(N-M)` sensor values, do `model.forecast(n_periods=M)` and calculate the `MSE` between the labels (the last `M` values) and the predictions (what comes out of `model.forecast`).

Comment: This is very clear. Thanks very much and thats exactly what i did. However, I read about ARIMA over and over again in the last weeks and i still fail to understand why we do not use the estimated cofficients in AR, MA or both to do the forecast in the future. You are saying that ARIMA does not have weights but weights and coefficients are for me the same thing arent they?.  Y(t) = coeff1 * Y(t-1) + coeff 2 * Y(t-2) + error .... coeff1 and coeff2 are still weights right? in this case, why are they not used? Thanks a lot

Comment: That is more a theoretical question than a coding question, you should probably ask a new SO question.

Comment: Thanks Frederik. True thanks to you i do understand the coding question better but theoretically or mathematically i am still unsure how the forecasting is done. You said there are no weights so i am not sure how it is done. if you could point me to an article or pdf that explains this part it would be very appreciated. I thank you again for all your help

Comment: i think that the forecast for each point is generated using the full history up to that point which means that at the end of N start the M values (chopped values). Therefore, the first M value is generated using N only, the second M value is generated  using N + the previously estimated M value......   We use the previous forecast to generate the next forecast....that s the only explanation that comes to my mind ......however i am still puzzled about the remark you made on weights

Comment: You _can_ view the parameters as weights if you want, they are just not weights as they are referred to in a Neural Network setting. What I said was : `...does not have any weights it trains in a training phase...` . It _does_ have parameters that change based on inputs, they are just not "trained" like they are in NNs.